# How to check network availability in my Perl module tests?

Tags: perl, networking, testing, curl

Working on a Perl module using networking tasks, I have to check the network availability or failure when testing. More exactly, I need to test network availability, then a specific API availability.

Here is some code from my `api-interraction.t` test :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

# Foo::Module is using WWW::Curl::Simple
my $requester = Foo::Module->new();

my $query = "http://existing-doma.in?with=some&useful=parameters";
# We should be able to test a bad request too
my $wrong_query = "http://deaddoma.in";

my $api_test_code = $requester->get_api_status($query);

if ($api_test_code == 200) {
    cmp_ok($api_test_code, "==", 200, "API reachable - HTTP status = 200");
} else {
    cmp_ok($api_test_code, "!=", 200, "API not reachable - HTTP status != 200");
}
```

It seems it can't work when network fails. Any recommendation on how I could achieve this better ?

Comment: Seems that `WWW::Curl::Simple` is not the right tool to use? What about `Net::Ping`? Does it cover all the possible cases (computer disconnected from network, API returning *problem* status or shutdown, etc.)

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you want the test to behave: if the network is down, should the test FAIL or SKIP?

Comment: @ tobyink I would say that the test should fail, because the module is useless without network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Test::More tests => 1;

my $query = "http://existing-doma.in";
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $browser->get( $query );

is $response->code, 200;
```

Comment: Not sure why my answer was downvoted. It works, and the code is simpler than the example provided. IMO, the purpose of testing is to verify working code. If the network is down, and the test fails, the error code that's returned is what the tester needs to resolve the issue. Testing "is the network up" first is pointless, since it's not testing the code it's testing the environment. If the query succeeds, the network was up. If it doesn't, the tester needs to determine whether the cause was the code being tested or something outside the program's control.

Comment: Looks like the question is a moving target. It's been edited at least twice since I provided my (original) answer.